# How to use mouse enter event with codes?

Tags: c#

Imagine that i have 10 buttons and i want to use mouse enter event to increase buttons width and height by 30. if i want to do this i have to use mouse event for each of them one by one, 
how can i write my code only once for all buttons.i'm trying to use foreach loop but not sure if i should use form load and don't know how to handle event. (windows form)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace main
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (Control item in Controls)
            {
                if (item is Button)
                {
                    // code
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Subscribe them to same event handler `buttonMouseEnter` what will increase size of `sender`.

Comment: You should look through your class.Designer.cs files to get a proper understanding of the basic concepts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all shorten your code by getting *only* the buttons on the form. Then add an eventhandler for the `MouseEnter` event:

```
foreach (Button btn in Controls.OfType<Button>())
{
    btn.MouseEnter += new System.EventHandler(btn_MouseEnter);
}
```

Then in the event change the width:

```
private void btn_MouseEnter(object sender, System.EventArgs e) 
{
    var senderButton = (Button)sender;
    senderButton.Width += 30;
}
```

You'all also have to add an event handler + event for `MouseLeave` to decrease the width again. Otherwise the buttons will keep on growing:

```
foreach (Button btn in Controls.OfType<Button>())
{
    btn.MouseEnter += new System.EventHandler(btn_MouseEnter);
    btn.MouseLeave += new System.EventHandler(btn_MouseLeave );
}

private void btn_MouseEnter(object sender, System.EventArgs e) 
{
    var senderButton = (Button)sender;
    senderButton.Width += 30;
}

private void btn_MouseLeave (object sender, System.EventArgs e) 
{
    var senderButton = (Button)sender;
    senderButton.Width -= 30;
}
```

The foreach-loop code can be added after `InitializeComponent()` or in the `Form_Load` event.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (Button btn in Controls.OfType<Button>())
    {
        btn.MouseEnter += new System.EventHandler(btn_MouseEnter);
        btn.MouseLeave += new System.EventHandler(btn_MouseLeave );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can easily loop through your all buttons using [`OfType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360913%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) extension method like this:

```
foreach(var button in this.Controls.OfType<Button>())
{
    button.MouseEnter += button_MouseEnter;
}
```

Comment: You can write it in the `load`

Answer (score 1):

Use functions to wrap your logic.

Write your code that change the weight and width in method, an subscribe  to [MouseMove or whatever event that suits you](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.mousemove.aspx).

Then use [GetChildAtPoint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a6zktd23.aspx) to locate the button, so you can change its size.

```
// This goes in the 
foreach(var button in this.Controls.OfType<Button>())
{
    button.Mouse += button_IncreaseSize;
}


protected override void button_IncreaseSize(MouseEventArgs e)
{
   // use GetChildAtPoint to get the control
   var button = GetChildAsPoint(new Point(e.X, e.Y));
   // Change the size of button, eg. with Scal, and with the Size property, or by chaning Height and Width propertis manually
   button.Scale(new SizeF(30, 30));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can also do this:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{              
    foreach (Control item in this.Controls)
    {
        if (item is Button)
        {
            //item.MouseEnter += (s, ea) => { YourMethodName(); };
              item.MouseEnter += new System.EventHandler(btn_MouseEnter);
        }
    }
}

private void btn_MouseEnter(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
   //your code to increase width and height
    var btnSenderButton = sender as Button;
    btnSenderButton.Width += 30;
}
```

Comment: This is also a working solution but considering the OP probably doesn't understand the complete concept of event handling, this solution might be confusing or non-understandable.

Comment: Yes. You are right. But I have just noticed `Form1` instance here. Why it is used?

Comment: I have no idea, I left it out in my answer. With given information from the OP I don't see any use for it.

Comment: sorry i was working on sth else and forgot to remove instance

Comment: ok @Riddle I am going to edit and delete last instructions :)